# Equivalent of Union_map in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have been trying to find the union_map() equivalent in pig. I know for sure that *TOMAP* function brings in *MAP datatype.*

But the requirement is to bring all the *MAPs* for a given id as  shown below.

```
select I1,UNION_MAP(MAP(Key,Val)) as new_val group by I1;
```

Sample Input and result is provided below.

### Input

ID,Key,Val

ID1,K1,V1

ID2,K1,V2

ID2,K3,V3

ID1,K2,V4

ID1,K1,V7

select ID,UNION_MAP(TO_MAP(Key,VAL)) from table group by ID;

### Result

ID1,(K1#V7,K2#V4)

ID2,(K1#V2,K3#V3)

I would like to get the similar output in pig.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download  the `piggybank.jar` from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpiggybankjar.htm and set it in your classpath and try the below approach.

**input**

```
ID1,K1,V1
ID2,K1,V2
ID2,K3,V3
ID1,K2,V4
ID1,K1,V7
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID:chararray,Key:chararray,Val:chararray);
B = RANK A;
C = GROUP B BY (ID,Key);
D = FOREACH C {
                sortByRank = ORDER B BY rank_A DESC;
                top1 = LIMIT sortByRank 1;
                GENERATE  FLATTEN(top1);
              }
E = GROUP D BY top1::ID;
F = FOREACH E {
                 ToMap = FOREACH D GENERATE TOMAP(top1::Key,top1::Val);
                 GENERATE group,BagToTuple(ToMap) AS myMap;
              }

DUMP F;
```

**Output:**

```
(ID1,([K1#V7],[K2#V4]))
(ID2,([K1#V2],[K3#V3]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as you see that for ID1 only K1#V7 should be there and not both the values. The basic property of MAP is to insert a new key if the key is already present then it needs to update the value for the key.

Comment: @RakeshShrama, Pig MAP wont support the property that you mentioned, it will just store the key value pair of the given values. If you want to create something like this in Pig MAP then you have write your own logic. I have modified the solution as per your need and its working fine, Can you check it?